# How to see the current keyboard layout in Windows, i.e. which keys will give which symbols

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, windows-11

I'm using a Swedish keyboard on my Windows 11 laptop, with three languages installed: English UK, English US, Swedish. I find it hard to work out where various symbols are if I'm using a different language than Swedish, since the location depends on current windows keyboard layout.

If I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to change keyboard layout to Swedish then I can look at the physical keyboard. The symbols on each key indicate what character I'll get if I press that key. Obviously. But when I've switched to English UK or English US, is there a way to get a similar picture of the current windows keyboard layout, so I can see what character I'll get when I press each key? So I can see for example what happens if I press the key beneath the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key, or press the key to the left of the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key.

Right now I tend to either

- fumble around pressing all the keys I can think of whenever I want a `~`, `#`, `\` etc
- or I use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>  to switch to a language that I know where the key is, type the symbol, then <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> a few times to switch back again.

[It seems like](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111624/how-to-display-the-current-keyboard-layout) `xkeycaps` does this sort of thing in Unix land.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use the [KbdEdit](https://www.kbdedit.com/) software for that purpose.
It's paid software but does the job beautifully. Here's how English UK keyboard looks with `SHIFT` key pressed

[image: English UK keyboard with shift key pressed]

I've used it for years to customize my keyboard layout (turn right `CTRL` into `DEL` among others)

Comment: Looks olde skool but great, thanks

Comment: Author is a great guy, I've been getting my lifetime updates for the last 10 years or more. Always works flawlessly.

Comment: The problem is not all keyboard layouts are shown in kbedit. For instance, the Kannada phonetic layout is not shown at all - perhaps because it is not strictly a conventional layout, but a ["smart"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-set-up-and-use-indic-phonetic-keyboards-7c4d2e8a-abf2-f200-9866-1a4cead7b127) one that pops up a dynamic suggestion list.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a setting which will not change dynamically, I'd suggest you save the relative layouts as images on your desktop, or print them out on paper: this will be in any case much faster to access than to fumble around in Windows settings. Since you're using Windows 11, you could also create a snap layout with the image of the keyboard and of your favorite text-editing software.

You can find the relative keyboard layouts for US and UK [in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/British_and_American_keyboards), from which I've copied the images for you.

***US International keyboard layout:***
[image: US International keyboard layout]

***United Kingdom Extended keyboard layout:***
[image: United Kingdom Extended keyboard layout]

Answer (score 1):

The Windows On-Screen Keyboard can show your keyboard layout and is
also a means for entering keys via the mouse.

See the Microsoft article
[Use the On-Screen Keyboard (OSK) to type](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-the-on-screen-keyboard-osk-to-type-ecbb5e08-5b4e-d8c8-f794-81dbf896267a).

The OSK is the biggest help that Windows can give.
Otherwise, you could post it a a background image on your desktop,
post stickers on the keys, or any other method you could think of
and can do yourself.

Comment: My on screen keyboard is always completely different, eg has lots fewer symbol keys. It doesn’t look like it’s trying to depict the physical keyboard I have, rather it’s an alternative that’s probably always the same (for a given language) regardless of hardware.

Comment: Link fixed. OSK shows a simplified (working) image of the layout which can be used to identify the placement of the keys. Windows has no way of knowing what your physical keyboard is like, it just receives key-codes when you press keys.

Comment: thanks, I kind-of get that windows doesn't know what my physical keyboard looks like ... but on the other hand there's probably a 'normal' layout for a Swedish keyboard and/or for certain keys. It knows where the number keys usually are and it knows what symbols it'll output when i press SHIFT-3, so I wish it would make it easy for me to find out.

Comment: The OSK is the biggest help that Windows can give. Otherwise, you could post images on your desktop, or other methods that you do yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the settings from the bottom panel - or press the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key and choose settings. From there press language and time.

[image]

Scroll/go to language and region - you'll see the list on installed languages. Press the 3 dots next to your language.

[image]

Choose add a keyboard layout.

[image]

I apologize as my system is in Hebrew, but I think you'll do fine if you follow the above steps.

Comment: Thanks for the pics & steps. But do you get to see a picture of a keyboard anywhere showing which buttons will give which symbols? PS: welcome to superuser!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official MS Keyboard Layout Creator for that: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134

[MS Keyboard Layout Creator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8UO6.png)

1. Install the MSKLC
2. Start the App
3. Klick File > Load Existing Layout
4. Select your layout (e.g. United States-International)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft lists all their supplied keyboard layouts on their website. You can see them here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/globalization/keyboards/kbdusx

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).